Odometry problems with clearpath robots
Currently working with the Jackal and Husky Clearpath models. Trying to test some sensing, however the odometry is very inconsistent. The positive and negative signs will switch without any explanation between different run times and instantiations for both x and y values. Tried to test several times under different conditions, and I cannot find a reason for this. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any ideas?

Tested restarting instance to see if it changes per instance
Rerunning and measuring odometry. inconsistent each time I ran it
Tried mapping out proposed y and x axis robot could be strictly depending on, but unless the axes are changing, this is not plausible.

Overall very inconsistent, and I cannot recognize any patterns to work off of.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
